# Mapping area when DF has geometry, how?

Tags: r, maps

See following. How can I plot a map, since there in DF there is no lat/long, but just "geometry"
THX!!!

```
library(mapsFinland)

fin<-mapsFinland::kunnat2019
view(fin)

ggplot(fin, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
  geom_polygon()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this, you will need another package, sf, this is from the book geocomputation in R.

ggplot supports plotting geometries with the geom_sf geometry, when you have the sf package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mapsFinland)
library(sf)

fin<-mapsFinland::kunnat2019
view(fin)

ggplot(fin) +
  geom_sf()
```

Answer (score 0):

@JuriJ "geometry" points to the simple feature `{sf}` package. `{sf}` enables you to do many geo-spatial operations. Install the sf package for that. There is support for sf-object plotting and ggplot.

```
   # load what you need
   library(mapsFinland)
   library(sf)
   library(ggplot2)

   # read/load sf map of finland
   fin<-mapsFinland::kunnat2019

   ggplot() + 
   # if you add elements to your map, I recommend to specify the data
   # in the geom_call 
     geom_sf(data = fin)
```

[image]